# How to configure SSH keys when you push to Heroku from two separate laptops

Tags: git, heroku, ssh

Ideally, I want to be able to work from my windows or mac transparently on the same project which I want to keep remotely on github and heroku.My ssh keys are identical on my github account, my heroku account and my windows pc. I am now migrating most of my development work from my windows platform to my new mac. I read "It’s generally a good idea to login and add your public key immediately after installing the heroku toolbelt so that you can use git to push or clone Heroku app repositories".

I was not allowed to push remote on the windows pc, when I tried to rename the ssh keys. On the mac, I am confused at to whether I need to delete the git generated keys and copy the same ssh keys as I use everywhere else. If I am to keep  the git generated keys on my mac how do I proceed if the two machines are each identified by their own ssh keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku needs to know the public keys of the different devices you’re making ssh connections from —the same goes for Github—.

For example: If you buy a computer, make a Public SSH Key for him, load your identities into your authentication agent, and tell Heroku about your public key (probably would be good if you add them to your Github account too).

If you’re missing the last step, in Heroku’s Account menu you can add the Public SSH Keys.

Comment: I would like to mention that I skipped the git init part on the mac as I saw no reason to re-initialize the existing one.

Comment: You only needed a Git clone.

Comment: Thanks Luis. I am marking you as the right answer but in all fairness it could just as well gone to John who tipped me to do heroku git:remote.  Still puzzled about ssh -T git@heroku.com giving a "shell request failed on channel 0".

Answer (score 1):

SSH keys identify you as the user and not the computer - although they do typically have the signature of the machine that generated them at the end.

Copy the keys into ~/.ssh keys on your Mac and then clone your app from Github, once cloned go into the folder and do `heroku git:remote` which will add a `heroku` remote to your local repo and allow you to do `git push heroku master`

Comment: IMHO SSH Keys don't identify users, they identify computers. They can identify users, in the case of Github and Heroku, but that's because of transitivity. I don't know if you agree with me. Maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: Jul 21, 2014 - SSH keys are a way to identify trusted computers source :https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys. This key is used to gain access on systems which have your private key listed in their authorized keys file. source:http://sshkeychain.sourceforge.net/mirrors/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO-4.html

Comment: I created the heroku app on my PC. My main objective was to make a change to a single file on that app from my mac. I created new default keys on the mac, added these to both github and did a heroku keys:add.  After doing a heroku git:remote and a git push heroku master, i confirmed that my changes to the file was shown both locally and on heroku. I have not tried to copy the old keys to the mac and may leave that for another day if there is a good reason someone can give. ssh -T git@heroku.com gives a "shell request failed on channel 0". Should this be a concern?